# Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets. Prove that $(A - B)\cap C = (A\cap C) - B = (A\cap C) - (B\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I was trying to prove the proposed relations as exhibited next:

$(A-B)∩ C \ =\
\sim((A-B) \implies \sim C) \ =\
\sim(\sim(A-B)∪ C)$

But I failed so far.

Comment: What is `-->` supposed to mean here?

Comment: the meaning is it implies sir...

Comment: Hint: show each set $\owns x$ iff $x\in A\land x\notin B\land x\in C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us prove the first claim first:

\begin{align*}
(A - B)\cap C & = A\cap B^{c}\cap C\\\\
& = (A\cap C)\cap B^{c}\\\\
& = (A\cap C) - B
\end{align*}

Now let us prove the second claim (in the reverse order):

\begin{align*}
(A\cap C) - (B\cap C) & = (A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C)^{c}\\\\
& = (A\cap C)\cap(B^{c}\cup C^{c})\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c}\cap C)\cup(A\cap C\cap C^{c})\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c}\cap C)\cup\varnothing\\\\
& = (A\cap C)\cap B^{c}\\\\
& = (A\cap C) - B
\end{align*}

Comment: how do you know  (A−B)∩C=A∩Bc∩C since c is not universal set?

Comment: @samuelcrhis Could you be more specific? I have applied the relation $A - B = A\cap B^{c}$.

Comment: sorry sir I was wrong do you have a table of the relations of sets?

Comment: @samuelcrhis you can check out Munkres' Topology book. Particularly the first chapter.

Comment: thank you Átila Correia

Comment: @samuelcrhis you are welcome! I am glad to help.